# Почему программа не работает?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

double x, y, R;
int main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
printf("Введите x, y:\n");
scanf("%lf%lf", &x, &y);
R = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
if(((x >= -7) && (y >= 0) && (x <= 7) && (y <= 7)) || (R <= 3.5));
{
    printf("Точка принадлежит заданной области\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Точка не принадлежит заданной области\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

VS ошибок не выдает указывая на `else` красной волнистой линией.
Точку с запятой убрал - она заработала, но при в воде `x = 1`, `y = -3` выдает неправильный результат: "Точка не принадлежит заданной области". Хотя R = 3.1 что меньше `3.5` и предполагается ответ "Точка принадлежит заданной области", в чем проблема?

Comment: `if(((x >= -7) && (y >= 0) && (x <= 7) && (y <= 7)) || (R <= 3.5));` точка с запятой в конце строки - уберите

Comment: А откомпилировать не пробовали? Почему сообщения от компилятора нет в вопросе?

Comment: На самом деле -- принадлежит (и у меня копипаста работает, только `;` после `if` надо убрать и `#include <math.h>` для чистоты добавить). Думаю, что-то не то запускаете...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас после предложения с `if`

```
if(((x >= -7) && (y >= 0) && (x <= 7) && (y <= 7)) || (R <= 3.5));
                                                                ^^^
```

стоит точка с запятой. Уберите их.